# How to make an && operator in a JSrender if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I need the following if statement in a JSRender template:

```
if (UltimoStr != "0,00" && BudgetStr != "0,00" && ReseveretStr != "0,00")
{
<div class="Posts"></div>  
}
```

but i can't figure out the syntax.

What i have so far is:

```
{{if UltimoStr != "0,00"}} and {{BudgetStr != "0,00"}} and {{ReseveretStr != "0,00"}}
<div class="Posts"></div>  
{{/if}}
```

which isn't working.

I've been looking at this site for documentation, but it doesnt seem to have multiple and operators:

https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/demos/scenarios/02_separators-scenario.html

Comment: It looks as if you misinterpreted the sample above (separators scenario) in which the {{if}} {{else}} is being used to insert the string separator "and". So the "and" is nothing to do with the logical operator &&.
This is a simpler example which does use "&&" :https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/demos/step-by-step/10_comparison-tests.html#L40.
The reply from JcFx below looks correct to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
{{if UltimoStr != "0,00" && BudgetStr != "0,00" && ReseveretStr != "0,00"}}
    <div class="Posts"></div>  
{{/if}}
```

Alternatively, you could decorate the object you are binding with a single Boolean that calculates the result of that expression.

A list of operators that work in JsRender can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975379.aspx (scroll down to the section titled Expressions).

Here's a simple test:

```
HTML:

<body>
    <h2>Result</h2>
    <div id="expect-true"></div>
    <div id="expect-false"></div>
</body>

<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{:UltimoStr}}
    {{:BudgetStr }}
    {{:ReseveretStr }}
    {{if UltimoStr != "0,00" && BudgetStr != "0,00" && ReseveretStr != "0,00"}}
        <h1>True!</h1>
    {{else}}
        <h1>False!</h1>
    {{/if}}
</script>

//JS:
$(document).ready(function() {
    var trueData = {
        UltimoStr: "1,00",
        BudgetStr: "1,00",
        ReseveretStr: "1,00"
    };
    $("#expect-true").append($("#template").render(trueData));

    var falseData = {
        UltimoStr: "0,00",
        BudgetStr: "0,00",
        ReseveretStr: "0,00"
    };
    $("#expect-false").append($("#template").render(falseData));
});
```

Seems to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/FJSkh/2/

Comment: Your other suggestion will obviously work, but does not answer the question :)

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - what happens? Do you get an error, or is the result not what you expect, or ...?  I've just tested using `&&` in the same structure in a template of my own, and it works as expected.

Comment: It doesnt create the div where it is supposed to. Using a single if statement on any of the variables works, just not when combined with && :S

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/FJSkh/ - or did I misunderstand what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Kenci - if it doesn't work, maybe you are using a very old version of JsRender - before the support for logical operators was added?